# React - easy solution for global state or antipattern?

Tags: reactjs, state, this, global

In my React app I have main component that contians the whole state of the application and also functions used to modify the state.

In order to get access to the state and the functions in all subcomponents I'm passing `this` from the main component through subcomponent attributes (`app`):

```
class App extends React.Component {

  state = DefaultState;
  funcs = getController(this);

  render() {
    return (
      <Header app={this} />
      <Page app={this} />
      <Footer app={this} />
    )
  }
}


function getController(app: App) {
  return {
    switchPage: (page: string) => {
      app.setState({ page: page });
    },
  }
}
```

Therefore in subcomponents I can access the state variables and modify them like this:

```
const HeaderComponent: React.FC<CompProps> = (props) => {
  return (
    <div>
      <h1>{props.app.state.currentPage}</h1>
      <button onClick={(e) => {props.app.funcs.switchPage('home')}}>Home</button>
    </div>
  )
}
```

This is the quickest/simplest solution I've found for global state. However I've never seen this in any tutorial or so. I guess main problem is the whole app will rerender when a single value is changed in global state, but the same goes for React Context API.

Question is that are there any disadvantages of this approach or a reason to not use this?

Comment: I wouldn't imagine that you would want the whole app to update when one piece of state changes. React was designed in a way to avoid this and to only allow components to update if needed which provides a fast and user intuitive UI. If you update the app each time it would re render every component. You could use useMemo to check state changed for each sub component, but this seems like a lot of work when there plenty of state management options out there.

Also this method requires using prop drilling which can get very messy in larger projects.

Comment: I'm using this for the purpose of simplicity and easiness of development for relatively simple apps. I've never experienced any performance issues so far.

Comment: It will work, but it's not the 'React' way of doing things and React was actively designed to avoid this style of state management. The issues will arise if your simple apps start to get larger and more complicated.

Comment: It's like passing around the class that contains Main in Java or C#. It works but introduces unnecessary coupling. You should use Contexts at least. So, yes, this one looks like an antipattern.

Comment: It wont work on the long run unless your app is really small and simple.  The real way to do this is to use a store like react-redux or mobx

Comment: Why don't you use `React.useRef` it is mostly the same and is completely react-ish?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can save `func` to an exported let variable and utilize the most recent version of `func` without re-rendering, but as this isn't a common occurrence, you won't find much information about it. Since it's simply javascript, any known hack will work. Also, the part of your question regarding react-context re-rendering is correct although you must consider that it will re-render and it will be more pruned for optimization of unmodified siblings.

You may alternatively supply a simple ref (`useRef`) to those components, which will allow them to access the most recent version of `func`, but because the ref reference itself does not change when the page is re-rendered, they will not be updated for function change.

I'm using react functional component but the class base may be so similar

```js
export let funcs = null

const App = () => {
  funcs = getController();
  render() {
    return (
      <Header />
      <Page />
      <Footer />
    )
  }
}

// header component
import { funcs as appFuncs } from '~/app.js'
const HeaderComponent: React.FC<CompProps> = (props) => {
  return (
    <div>
      {/* same thing can be happened for the state */}
      <button onClick={(e) => {appFuncs.switchPage('home')}}>Home</button>
    </div>
  )
}
```

**Hooks version**

```js
const App = () => {
  const ref = useRef();
  funcs = getController();
  ref.current = {state, funcs};

  // note ref.current changes not the ref itself
  render() {
    return (
      <Header app={ref} />
      <Page app={ref} />
      <Footer app={ref} />
    )
  }
}

// header
const HeaderComponent: React.FC<CompProps> = (props) => {
  return (
    <div>
      <h1>{props.app.current.state.currentPage}</h1>
      <button onClick={(e) => {props.app.current.func.switchPage('home')}}>Home</button>
    </div>
  )
}
```

Any suggestions or other techniques will be much appreciated.